# WordPress Login via Identity Server 4

Tags: wordpress, identityserver4

Wordpress is to be given the opportunity to log on via Identity Server 4: We have entered the necessary data in Wordpress (most recently with the plugin "OAuth Single Sign On - SSO (OAuth client)") and tried to address the Identity Server. Please note the picture attached.

Settings of the WordPress plugin:
[image: Wordpress plugin settings]

Unfortunately we always get the message

> Error: Sorry, there was an error : unauthorized_client. The plugin
>   sends the following request URL:
>   http://yyyyyy.com/connect/authorize?client_id=wp-internal&scope=openid%20email&redirect_uri=https://xxxxxx.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=openid-connect-authorize&response_type=code&state=V29yZHByZXNzIENsaWVudCBJbnRlcm5hbA===

As far as we can see, the statement is correct - and now we have no meaningful idea what we can do. Can you help or do you have an idea?

Configuration on IdentityServer4 is:

```
new Client
            {
                ClientId = "wp-internal",
                ClientName = "Wordpress Client Internal",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = false,
                RequireConsent = true,

                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("#dfmsgmwpgdidsa2019".Sha256())
                },

                RedirectUris = { "https://xxxxxx.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=openid-connect-authorize" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://xxxxxx.com/" },
                FrontChannelLogoutUri = "https://xxxxxx.com/logout",
                LogoUri = "https://xxxxxx.com/logout",
                AllowedCorsOrigins =     { "https://xxxxxx.com" },


                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email
                },

                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true
            },
```

Comment: Share the identity server startup and config code or else it’s not gonna be easy to help

Comment: I added the code above. Thanx!

Comment: Well your redirect uri is `https://yyyyy.com` in the word press plugin generated uri but in your config it is `https://xxxxx.com`. So not sure if it issue with you trying to mask or not but if those uri values mismatch then that's exact error you will get that you are experiencing.

Comment: Sorry, thats me again - xxxx and yyy are just a placeholder for example1 and example 2 - i changed the description again

Comment: i checked the source for idsrv4 and firstly, you should get more error description in the response than just unauthorized client so check for that. Secondly, only 3 conditions seem to trigger this resoponse: client is not enabled or not exists, protocol type is not oidc or the redirect uri is not an exact match. You need to find which one you are triggering. Check the logs for idsrv4 also, it should give more clues.

Comment: Don't know if it is a typo or not but in the URL it says .com twice `redirect_uri=https://xxxxxx.com.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?`

Comment: it was a typo - i corrected it.

Comment: getting same error  @Florian is it resolve